# SQLSTATE[23000] necesito ayuda, laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'email' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `suscriptores` (`email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, 2020-05-01 20:09:13, 2020-05-01 20:09:13))

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 footer-newsletter ">
                    <h4>Novedades</h4>
                    <p>Suscribite a nuestra lista de visitantes y recibi novedades sobre nuestros trabajos</p>
                    @if(Session::has("success"))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get("success")}}</div>
                    @elseif(Session::has("fail"))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{Session::get("fail")}}</div>
                    @endif

                    <form action="/correo" method="post" required>
                        @csrf
                        <input type="text" name="email"><input type="submit" value="Suscribite">
                    </form>

                </div>

    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Web;

use App\Suscriptores;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class EmailController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $email = new Suscriptores;

        $email->email = $request->input('email', '@default');


        $email->save();


         if ($request->has(['email'])  ){
             return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Suscrito a nuestra lista con exito');
         }else{
             return redirect("/")->with("fail", "Intente nuevame mas tarde");
        }



    }


}



//ruta del formulario  action"/suscriptores"
Route::post('/correo', 'Web\EmailController@store');
/*
```

Comment: $email->save(); este no el insert en eloquent ?

Comment: Has un de de tu request ya que el error va en función de que no le está llegando algún valor

Comment: como puedo hacer si el usuario no inserta nada en formulario para quen o tire null

Comment: Coloca como NULL dicho atributo en las migraciones, así si el usuario no manda el email no te dará error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas validar que el formulario lleve el campo que esperas, puedes hacer uso de validate

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate(['email' => 'required']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado necesitaba crear un request requerid

```
$request->validate(['email' => 'required']);

$data = request()->validate([
            'email' => 'required|max:18'
        ]);
```

Comment: Cuál es la diferencia entre eso y lo que dice en la respuesta de @JonathanOrta?